# Nvidia X Server Settings is kind of empty

Tags: 18.10

I just installed Ubuntu 18.10 on my Gigabyte Aero 15X.
My GPU is a Nvidia GTX 1070 Max-Q.
I am using the nvidia-driver-415, I also tried 390, 394 and 410, the problem is always the same:

[image: Nvidia X Server Settings is empty]

I cannot do anything but change my GPU...

Comment: Maybe you updated kernel? Nvidia drivers is not fully supported by kernels >= 4.19.

Comment: That's what I see when the Nvidia driver isn't installed properly or not running.

Comment: I have the same. Installed with `sudo ubuntu-drivers autoinstall`